# How can I generate random blurred gradient color background with different random starting points on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, gradient

How can I generate random blur color on Flutter? I don't know how to search. How can I do that?

I want to create a blurred gradient color background with different random starting points.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using any widget that accepts a [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html), like a container, you can use [LinearGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html). Inside this gradient you can specify which colours you want, and where these colours should be positioned. To randomize this, you could have a big list of possible colours, and then get a certain amount of integers using the [Random](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-math/Random-class.html) class to select a few colours out of this list. You can also position these colours randomly using the **stops** property in the LinearGradient in combination with again that same Random class.

If a linear gradient is not what you want, there are also others, like [RadialGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RadialGradient-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to get somewhat close results shown in the picture by using

```
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment(0.8, 1),
            colors: <Color>[
              Color(0xff87c7b9),
              Color(0xffe6be84),
              Color(0xff8f66bd),
              Color(0xff8634c3),
              Color(0xffb11ba7),
            ],
            tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
          ),
        ),
```

Feel free to experiment with more colors